# Need to perform column merge on 1st column on multiple csv (1500 x 20) files imported from url with the help of a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Confused with how to store , access & mege dfs.c df columns have same header names.The code is below:

```
for s in range(40):
    # a func which returns historical business dates 
    ago_Ybd_0= 
    (date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2020,7,17),s,Holiday))
     year_0, month_0, day_0 = ago_Ybd_0.strftime("%Y-%b-%d").split("-")
     month_0 = month_0.upper()

    #import / unzip/ read file
    !wget 
    'https://www.ukp.com/content/historical/{year_0}/{month_0}/cm{day_0} 
    {month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip' 
    !unzip 'uk{day_0}{month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip'
    a_0=f'uk{day_0}{month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip' 



     # problem area

     c=f'uk{day_0}{month_0}{year_0}'
     c  = pd.read_csv(a_0,engine='python') 

 # merge
 eod_a=c.merge(c,on='SYSTEM',how='left')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a list of data frames then call [**`concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for horizontal merge:

```
def get_data(s):
    # a func which returns historical business dates 
    ago_Ybd_0 = (date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2020, 7, 17), s, Holiday))
    year_0, month_0, day_0 = ago_Ybd_0.strftime("%Y-%b-%d").split("-")
    month_0 = month_0.upper()

    #import / unzip/ read file
    !wget 
    'https://www.ukp.com/content/historical/{year_0}/{month_0}/cm{day_0} 
    {month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip' 
    !unzip 'uk{day_0}{month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip'
    a_0=f'uk{day_0}{month_0}{year_0}kp.csv.zip' 

    # RETURN DATA FRAME, SETTING SYSTEM AS INDEX
    return pd.read_csv(a_0, engine='python', index_col='SYSTEM')

# BUILD LIST OF DFs VIA LIST COMPREHENSION
df_list = [get_data(s) for s in range(40)]

# BIND ALL DFs BY COLUMNS INTO SINGLE DF
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis='columns')
```